# Java / Oracle Invalid Stored Procedure Created Without SQLExceptions

Tags: java, oracle, java-stored-procedures

I have following Java code that creates a stored procedure. To test it I am deliberately passing it invalid sql:

```
public void createStoredProcedure(@NotNull final StoredProcInfo storedProcInfo, @NotNull final ColumnInfoFactory columnInfoFactory, @NotNull final Connection con) {
    Statement createProcStmt = null;
    try {
      List<String> parameterDefinitions = Lists.newArrayList();
      for (StoredProcParmInfo parmInfo : storedProcInfo.getInParameters()) {
        parameterDefinitions.add(columnInfoFactory.generateParameterDefinition(parmInfo));
      }
      for (StoredProcParmInfo parmInfo : storedProcInfo.getOutParameters()) {
        parameterDefinitions.add(columnInfoFactory.generateParameterDefinition(parmInfo));
      }
      String createProcSql = String.format("CREATE Procedure %s (%s) AS BEGIN %s END;", storedProcInfo.getName(), StringUtils.join(parameterDefinitions.iterator(), ","), storedProcInfo.getBody());
      createProcStmt = con.createStatement();
      createProcStmt.execute(createProcSql);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
      Closer.close(createProcStmt, logger);
    }
  }
```

The method executes successfully. And when I look in the database, I see that a stored procedure was created but marked as an invalid object:
[image]

And the error is that an INTO clause was expected in the body of the procedure:
[image]

Why was an SQLException not thrown when the code that created the procedure was executed? Is this an Oracle driver setting? I have searched online but not found any helpful information.

Comment: What is the final value of string `createProcSql`?

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure SYSTEM.TestProc14460693508460000 (s IN NUMBER,out_cursor OUT ACTEK_TYPES.ref_cursor) AS BEGIN select * from producer; END;